# If $fg \in L^p$ and $f,g$ are positive functions on a domain with finite measure, then what can I say about $f,g$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $fg \in L^p(M)$, where $M$ is a measure space with finite and complete measure $\mu$. Assume that $f,g$ are positive measurable functions on $M$. Then, what can I say about $f,g$?

I am really struggle on this, could not conclude anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can conclude anything in particular, choose for instance a function $f\not=0$ and a function $g=\frac{F}{f}$ where $F\in L^p$. Thus $fg\in L^p$, but you can choose $f$ almost arbitrarly (without any sort of regularity).